# Reattaching to screen - Linux

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, pid

We run several screen instances from one box, eg. :

27185.pts-53.CentOS-57-64-minimal     (Detached)

27209.pts-53.CentOS-57-64-minimal     (Detached)

27281.pts-53.CentOS-57-64-minimal     (Detached)

Is there a way to ‘name’ a screen id, so instead of having to remember the exact PID, i use screen -x 1 for pid 27185, screen -x 2 for pid 27209 and screen -x 3 for pid 27281 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start the screen, you can use `-S` to set the sessionname (Source: http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen )

After you are in screen, you can rename the Session by entering the command mode:
    Ctrl+a
    :sessionname

You can read about the `:` here:
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_6.html

and the list of available commands is here:
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_9.html

Comment: It is not possible to reattach using the title as we do set the -t for every instance. Trying -S now, will update you in a minute

Comment: -S works!! Thanks!! no idea how i missed that, re-read the manual 100 times ..